# In Objective-C, how to test against macro definition value?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'd like to use

```
#define IS_APP_FULL_VERSION NO
```

and the code

```
isAppFullVersion = IS_APP_FULL_VERSION;
```

to set instance variable.  But is there a way to also do

```
#if IS_APP_FULL_VERSION == "NO"

// add some methods here

#endif
```

but it would give a compile error, and so is `#if (IS_APP_FULL_VERSION == "NO")`.  Is there a way to check it against `YES` and `NO`?  (check against the substitution value)

---

**Update:** it seems like `>` and `== 0` is allowed, such as

```
#if IS_APP_FULL_VERSION == 0
```

so we can actually use `0` and `1` for false and true, and use `== 1` to test, but it will be better if `YES` and `NO` can be used.

---

**Update 2:**

One possible solution turns out to be:

```
#define IS_APP_FULL_VERSION  1

#if IS_APP_FULL_VERSION

// add some methods here

#endif

isAppFullVersion = IS_APP_FULL_VERSION;
```

will all work, and we can just change `1` to `0` to toggle the code.

Comment: You have two problems here:  1) "NO" has a value of zero, and that substitution will occur before you test the variable's value.  2) There in no macro functionality to evaluate the expression `<String> == <String>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that the macro processor #if statement only has one data type -- integer.  All #if expressions are evaluated in integer, with undefined symbols being replaced with zero.  String expressions (including comparisons) cannot be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, normally, I would just use a flag macro rather than a value one, since there's only two cases here:

```
#define APP_IS_FULL_VERSION
```

Either define or don't define that macro. Then, if you later wanted to include/exclude code based on that, you can use:

```
#ifdef APP_IS_FULL_VERSION
    // Do something
#endif
```

(or `#ifndef` for the opposite case, obviously).

For the code segment, it's a simple matter of using that to select the correct code:

```
#ifdef APP_IS_FULL_VERSION
    isAppFullVersion = YES;
#else
    isAppFullVersion = NO;
#endif
```

Comment: `NO` is a defined symbol in objective-c (it means false)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you're some confused comparison MACRO.

`#define` format is following it.

**`#define MACRO_NAME VALUE`** (`VALUE` is blank spaces are also fine. `MACRO_NAME` need is.)

if you want comparison compile-time following like it. this is comparison mean only `defined` vs `no defined`. not `YES` vs `NO`

```
#define IS_APP_FULL_VERSION 1

#if defined IS_APP_FULL_VERSION
    NSLog(@"full-verison");
#endif
```

---

```
#define IS_APP_FULL_VERSION blahblah

#if defined IS_APP_FULL_VERSION
        NSLog(@"full-verison");
#endif
```

If you want to build separate versions of. refer a following like it.

```
#define IS_APP_FREE_VERSION

#if defined IS_APP_FREE_VERSION
     NSLog(@"free-version");
#endif
```

---

```
#define IS_APP_FULL_VERSION

#if defined IS_APP_FULL_VERISON
     NSLog(@"full-version");
#endif
```

---

---

if you want comparison runtime following like it. this is comparsion normally.

```
#define IS_APP_FULL_VERSION 1    

if(IS_APP_FULL_VERSION)
{
    NSLog(@"full-verison");
}
```

---

```
#define IS_APP_FULL_VERSION 0    

if(!IS_APP_FULL_VERSION)
{
    NSLog(@"no full-version");
}
```